# How to get (large) image to auto-fit iframe?

Tags: image, iframe, autoresize

In firefox, "over-sized" images will auto-fit to an iframe. Other browsers do not have this feature. How to get an "over-sized" image to auto-fit in an iframe, when page is viewed with different browsers?

If you take firefox browser and look at: https://www.transitum.de/test/, you will see that the picture is perfectly displayed within the iframe.

If you take a different browser, like edge or chrome, and look at www.transitum.de/test/, you will see that only part of the picture is displayed.

The code I have used so far is:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://www.mirpir.eu/images/video jukebox 2018-12-21.jpg" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"  width="100%" height="510" related="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you able to put the example into a Stack Snippet? I imagine the `/test/` page will be deleted at some point.

Comment: Your prior questions are often relying on external links, and some of them are 404, which means they are off-topic. Please don't do this - if those questions are put on hold, as perhaps they should be, your account could be automatically stopped from asking new questions.